# How to incorporate changing variables in a function in R?

Tags: r, function, dplyr, data-wrangling

I am trying to create a function with the input being different variables of data frame.
In the end, I'd like to get a function output with the two different variables.

```
Name <- c("Jon", "Bill", "Maria", "Ben", "Tina", "Bill", "Maria")
Age <- c(23, 41, 32, 58, 26, 41, 32)

mydf <- data.frame(Name, Age)
var_name_input<- c("Name","Age") # this is where I think needs to be changed
```

```
generate_new_df<-function(var_name){
mydf %>% group_by(var_name) %>% count()}
```

```
generate_new_df(var_name = var_name_input[2]) # or 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
generate_new_df <- function(your_df, var_1, var_2) {
  your_df %>% 
    group_by({{var_1}}, {{var_2}}) %>% 
    count()
}

generate_new_df(df, Name, Age)

# A tibble: 5 × 3
# Groups:   Name, Age [5]
  Name    Age     n
  <chr> <dbl> <int>
1 Ben      58     1
2 Bill     41     2
3 Jon      23     1
4 Maria    32     2
5 Tina     26     1
```

Comment: Is the {{  }} needed in order to denote changing variables? I tried with a more complicated code, but supposedly same logic, and I get an error Error in `dots_list()`:
! Can't use `{{` in a non-quoting function
Backtrace:
 1. global generate_plot_for_recent_4_weeks(...)
 4. rlang::abort(message = message)

Comment: Also, since I have more than two variables IRL, how should I write the var_name_input<- c("Name","Age"), and incorporate later to the function, so I can put in more than two variables?